# PHP - Get name and directory of current script excluding domain?

Tags: php, path, dns

I am working on a product catalog. The directory structure is 3 levels deep from the domain root.

So say for instance I have a product page for an orange. And the orange is in a sub category called citrus, which is in a category called fruit which is in a directory called products. so the real path to this page would be `http://www.mydomain.com/products/fruit/citrus/orange.php`

Now, how would I get only the following: `/fruit/citrus/orange` when running `orange.php`

I have tried : `dirname(__FILE__);` but this gives an output of `http://www.mydomain.com/products/fruit/citrus/orange` which includes the domain which I do not want.

Could anyone offer any suggestions or advice on how I could accomplish something like this?

Thank you!

Comment: Use `$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$levels = 3;
$temp = array();

$parts = explode('/', $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']);
for ($i = 0; $i < $levels; $i++) {
  $temp[] = pathinfo(array_pop($parts), PATHINFO_FILENAME);
}
$temp[] = '';

$result = implode('/', array_reverse($temp));
```

Comment: Thank you for your reply. It is a perfect solution. But I notice that you have made use of `php_self` Could you suggest any uses where this function should not be used. This is as when researching info relating to this question I came a general dislike for this function, but I am not quite sure as to why?

Comment: @BlackberryFan Sorry that was actually not the best choice for this information. The reason for this is that `PHP_SELF` contains the actual file system path of the currently executing script relative to document root, and if the URL has been rewritten to get to your file it may not be correct. The best thing to use for this specific task is `REQUEST_URI`, and I have updated the answer accordingly.

Comment: Thanks Dave, I really appreciate your input and the extra advice too. It does make perfect sense what you say!